# Android: Fragment is added below childview

Tags: android

I have a `FrameLayout` with a few `buttons`, and some `ImageViews`. When I add a fragment, it shows on top of the `ImageViews` as expected but below the `buttons` but I don't know why.

I searched through a lot of the SO posts but couldn't find problems similar to mine.
I have a custom `onClickListener` that adds the fragment
Custom clickListener class:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // a context is passed to the listener 
    // this gets rootview id
    int id= ((ViewGroup)((Activity)context).getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0).getId();
    MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft = ((Activity) context).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(id, myFragment, "F1");
    ft.commit();
}
```

The View I am adding the fragment to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/startscreen"
>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/gamelogo"
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    />
</FrameLayout>
```

Activity:

```
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.startmenu);
    final FrameLayout r = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.startscreen);
    addViews(r);
}
public void addViews(FrameLayout r){
    // add some buttons to r
    // add custom OnClickListener to one of the buttons
    // add some ImageViews
    // add animation to one button
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display a single item. Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold a single child view, because it can be difficult to organize child views in a way that's scalable to different screen sizes without the children overlapping each other.

That's from the Docs, did you considered to change the layout?

Comment: It was actually `RelativeLayout` Before and then some post suggested to change it to `FrameLayout` so I tried that too. Neither works

Answer (score 0):

I figured that I have to add the fragment to the parent of the base FrameLayout. I don't know why I would have to do that though.